# glitch when I try to crossfade between two sinusoidal signals back and forth in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to create some functions in Matlab that is going to record a tone and then play it back semi-continuous. For example I want the user to be able to whistle for 2 seconds and the whistle to be dragged out to 10 seconds. I want to avoid using fancy time stretch algorithms but just use this through repetitions. I know there's issues with this but I'm doing this for experiment.

To do this, I need to crossfade the beginning and end of the sound to make it seem continuous. I have written a crossfade function that takes two signals and fades between them.

The idea is to have a sigmoid volume function that goes from 1 to 0 for the old sound and 0 to 1 for the new. I then just multiply the signal by this volume function and add the result. My understanding of the sigmoid function is that the resulting volume should be an average of the two input signals, with weight slowly moving from input signal a to input signal b, and the output amplitude should be the same as the input ones.

When I try this with two simple sinusoid input signals, however, and go back and forth between a low and high tone, I get a small "glitch" in the section just where it transfers from a low-to-high section, to a high-to-low sliding section. Where does this come from? I'm also not sure if this is only on my speakers, and I tried watching the plotted waveforms in time domain, but couldn't see anything weird happening at the specific time.

The end of the first section, and beginning of the last should have exactly the same frequency component, and nothing is moved in time, so I'm not sure where this glitch comes from.

Sample code:

(SLIGHT WARNING: This output some tones, one of which is a little bit high pitch, so maybe not play this with earphones on or with full volume).

```
function test()
Fs=44100;
x=1:1/Fs:2;
x=x'; %time vector
freq1 = 440; %low tone
freq2 = freq1*2^(7/12) % high tone (harmonic fifth)
Fs=44100;
x=1:1/Fs:2;
x=x'; %time vector
freq1 = 440; %low tone
freq2 = freq1*2^(7/12); % high tone (harmonic fifth)
y1 = sin(2*pi*x*freq1)
y2 = sin(2*pi*x*freq2)
res = stitchandrepeat(y1,y2, Fs);
end

function [out] = stitchandrepeat(in, in2, Fs)
lowtohigh = crossfade(in,in2,1);
hightolow = crossfade(in2,in,1);
out = [lowtohigh;hightolow];
out = [out;out];
out = [out;out];
out = [out;out];
end

function [out] = crossfade(a, b, sigmoid)
if not(size(a) == size(b))
    error('Different sizes');
end
index = (1:size(a,1))';
factor = index/size(a,1);
if(sigmoid)
    steepness = 5;
    factor = logsig((factor-0.5)*steepness*2);
end
plot(index, factor, 'o');
out = bsxfun(@times, a, 1-factor)+bsxfun(@times, b, factor);
end
```

I even tried doing a second crossfade where I stitched together the end and beginning of the first and second signal, but it still sounded a little bit weird just in the transition. Any idea on how to make the transition smooth?

```
function [out] = stitchandrepeat2(in, in2, Fs)
lowtohigh = crossfade(in,in2,1);
hightolow = crossfade(in2,in,1);
secstofade = 0.1;
len = size(lowtohigh,1);
partsize = secstofade*Fs;
lthpart = lowtohigh((len-partsize+1):len,:);
htlpart = hightolow(1:partsize,:);
lthcropped = lowtohigh(1:len-partsize,:);
htlcropped = hightolow(partsize+1:len,:);

highfade = crossfade(htlpart, lthpart,1);
out = [lthcropped;highfade;htlcropped];
out = [out;out];
out = [out;out];
out = [out;out];
end
```

And how come I don't get this glitch sound in the low part of the sound? (Two different sound waves are also just concatenated there.)